# Allowing Use of SSL Client Certificates on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

Where is the Windows 10 Pro setting that allows browsers to use SSL **client** certificates?

My client SSL certificate was imported and is shown under the Personal tab in the Windows certificate manager.  When I use Chrome, it never offers my client certificate to webservers that look for it.  Screenshot of the personal cert in Windows:

[image]

Everything works as expected in Firefox, which uses its own certificate keystore (not the Windows certificate management).  Makes me think the security settings on Windows may be too strict, and wondering where that might be. My Windows user has admin rights.  Firefox screenshot:

[image]

(personal info removed from above screenshots)

Comment: I suspect you've added it to the computer store (`certlm.msc`) and not the user store (`certmgr.msc`), which is where it should be.

Comment: Added screenshots above. Yes, was using `certmgr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging, I found a similar post which helped solve my Windows permission problem.  Post was:

[Unable to use client certificates in Chrome or IE on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1181163/unable-to-use-client-certificates-in-chrome-or-ie-on-windows-10)

Borrowing `kliron`'s steps, here's what I did, with new screenshots:

1. Client certificate is already installed (see certmgr screenshot above).
2. Start -> Run -> `mmc.exe`
3. File menu -> `Add/Remove Snap-In`
4. Double-click on `Group Policy Object Editor`
5. Accept default and press Finish. At this point, the Snap Ins dialog will look like:

[image]

6. Press OK to close the Add or Remove Snap-ins dialog
7. On the left side, expand `Console Root`. Continue expanding: `Local Computer Policy` -> `Computer Configuration` -> `Windows Settings` -> `Security Settings`, and click on `Public Key Policies` without expanding it.  Looks like this:

[image]

8. Double click on `Certificate Path Validation Settings`. Check `Define these policy settings` and check both `Allow user trusted root CAs to be used to validate certificates` and `Allow users to trust peer trust certificates`. Then, click the `Select Certificate Purposes` button.

[image]

9. On the Select Certificate Purposes, make sure `Client Authentication` is on the list (if not, select it from the dropdown and click `Add`).  Press OK to close the Select Certificate Purposes dialog.

[image]

10. Press OK to close the Certificate Path Validation Settings Properties dialog.
11. Close the window by hitting the X, or using `File` -> `Exit`.  If it asks to save, it is optional to save. Saving simply remembers the above steps taken, which you can give to another user to apply the same changes to Windows without having to repeat all the above steps. Save location should not matter.

[image]

12. After this, I restarted Chrome by going to URL `chrome://restart`.

When I visited my website, it successfully offered my SSL client certificate when my web server looked for it.

[image]